# Carbide vs. high speed steel in jointer blade

Tags: jointer, blade

I am replacing the cutters in my jointer and debating between high speed steel and carbide.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of HSS vs carbide jointer blades?

Comment: See related question about helical heads in planers; the same answers apply.

Comment: Mm. I asked two questions because I felt the other was more about the segmented spiral design vs straight blade, and this is aimed at the material the blade is made from. I understand carbide blades can't be made as sharp as HSS?

Comment: @keshlam you can get 3 blade cutters in both HSS and carbide

Comment: Valid points. But I think I did cover most of the tradeoffs there. Carbide will keep an edge longer but is harder to resharpen and is a larger investment.

Comment: Shall i close this one then, or does it have merit on its own?

Comment: I'd vote to keep it open - this is a material choice question, while the other is a design question. I thought we had another question about Carbide vs HSS saw blades, but some quick searching isn't turning one up.

Comment: Carbide blades came up in one of the answers to my question about gouges, someone suggested using carbide tool inserts to make a gouge. Even if there was, I think there's also a difference between a saw blade and a jointer knife that may make a difference in material choice, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All else being equal, anytime you have a choice between HSS (high speed steel) and carbide, you have to consider the tradeoffs.

**High-Speed Steel**

Advantages:

- Cheaper up-front
- Easier to sharpen
- Less brittle

Disadvantages:

- Potentially more expensive long-term (depending on application)
- Wears faster (must be sharpened or replaced more frequently)

**Carbide**

Advantages:

- Theoretically more cost-effective long-term (depending on application)
- More wear-resistant (often praised as lasting 10x as long as HSS)

Disadvantages:

- More expensive up-front
- More difficult to sharpen
- More brittle

**When does it matter?**

If you're looking at long jointer knives, high-speed steel is a proven material, and if you happen to completely trash your knives by running nails through your machine, the knives aren't very expensive to replace.

If you're looking at a cutterhead with segmented knives or inserts, carbide is a good choice because at worst you'll shatter the inserts that hit the nails.

Comment: HSS is easier to sharpen ... can they get comparable edges though, given enough effort on the carbide blade?

Comment: From my understanding, it depends on the size of grains in the carbide. Generally you cannot sharpen a carbide cutter quite as sharp as a steel cutter, but as both tools start to dull, the carbide one will hold its edge longer.

Comment: So far, in my many years in the woodshop and as a machinist, I've handled exactly ***one*** carbide insert that was as sharp as I can easily get HSS; that one insert was a fine finishing insert specifically for aluminum. I've never seen any carbide inserts in any profile that could match the sharpness of HSS. End mills, yes - they're built differently. Personally, I use HSS jointer & planer knives. I buy the steel once, resharpen & resharpen & resharpen... and it last a ***very long time***. Buy the carbide, and you end up buying a ***lot*** of it because you can't reasonably sharpen it.